# Como actualizar un valor en sql server de forma automática llegada una fecha

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla llamada `Cuota`, la cual tiene una `Fecha_vencimiento` (de tipo `Date`) y un `estado` (de tipo `varchar`). Necesito que cuando llegue la fecha de vencimiento el estado cambie, de forma automática, de `'VALIDA'` a `'VENCIDA'`.

No se si tengo que hacerlo con un procedimiento almacenado o con un trigger; de ser con alguno de estos 2, ¿Cómo hago que se ejecute automáticamente llegada la fecha de vencimiento?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dada la descripción del problema que estás dando, te voy a responder lo que NO estás preguntando, pues este es el típico caso del [problema xy](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3361/21).

Esto, porque si bien SQL Server tiene los mecanismos para realizar la tarea que buscas, realmente no hace falta complicar tanto las cosas si sigues el principio básico de **no almacenar** información derivada en las tablas.

Es decir, ya tienes la fecha de expiración y puedes averiguar en cualquier momento la fecha actual, con la función `getdate()`. Una simple comparación te dirá si una cuota está expirada o no.

Mantener almacenada, en otra columna, la misma información, pero de otra forma, por ejemplo, saber si está vencida o no, es redundante y suele ser una fuente de problemas por errores en la programación y/o configuración.

Dicho esto, con SQL server tampoco es necesario que escribas la regla que te dice el *status* del registro en cada consulta, ya que puedes tirar de las [columnas calculadas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15).

Por ejemplo, mira la sentencia de creación de esta tabla:

```
create table DatosExpiran (
    id                 bigint not null identity primary key
  , FechaExpiracion    datetime not null
  , compEstaExpirado   as case when FechaExpiracion < getdate() then 0 else 1 end
  , compEstadoActual   as case when FechaExpiracion < getdate() then 'VENCIDO' else 'VIGENTE' end
);
```

Si insertamos estos valores:

```
insert into DatosExpiran (FechaExpiracion) 
values ('20200101 17:12:14')
     , ('20211231 11:14:12')
     , (dateadd(ss, 60, getdate()));
```

Al ejecutar esta consulta:

```
select *, getdate() FechaActual
  from DatosExpiran;
```

Obtengo, al inicio, estos valores:

```
id                   FechaExpiracion         compEstaExpirado compEstadoActual FechaActual
-------------------- ----------------------- ---------------- ---------------- -----------------------
1                    2020-01-01 17:12:14.000 0                VENCIDO          2020-07-23 22:13:39.583
2                    2021-12-31 11:14:12.000 1                VIGENTE          2020-07-23 22:13:39.583
3                    2020-07-23 22:14:14.600 1                VIGENTE          2020-07-23 22:13:39.583

(3 rows affected)
```

Pero poco más de 1 minuto después, obtengo esto:

```
id                   FechaExpiracion         compEstaExpirado compEstadoActual FechaActual
-------------------- ----------------------- ---------------- ---------------- -----------------------
1                    2020-01-01 17:12:14.000 0                VENCIDO          2020-07-23 22:15:19.107
2                    2021-12-31 11:14:12.000 1                VIGENTE          2020-07-23 22:15:19.107
3                    2020-07-23 22:14:14.600 0                VENCIDO          2020-07-23 22:15:19.107

(3 rows affected)
```

Como puedes observar, la última fila ha *vencido* de manera automática al llegar la fecha/hora de vencimiento sin la necesidad de hacer nada más que el diseño de la tabla con columnas calculadas.

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo puedes lograr con el Agente de SQL Server, sin embargo deberás validar que tienes acceso a este o que tu versión del SQL Server lo tiene o soporta. Puedes ver algunos ejemplos en la [página de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/schedule-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15).